# How can I ask the smokers to stop smoking at playgrounds?

Tags: smoking-vaping, parenting

I can't stand anymore to encounter smoking parents as I visit playgrounds with my 3 years old daughter.

**Is there any constructive way to ask the smokers in order to stop smoking at playground?**

- I do not want a real escalation, it is playground
- I do not think I am there to educate anybody
- I do not want to just leave

The answer with experience would be appreciated.

**Objection**: passive smoking can lead to cancer and death.

**Goal**: avoiding escalation, avoid my child inhaling smoke but not leave the playground.

Comment: Are there posted rules against smoking at the playground? If there are signs or something that would probably help you a lot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this sounds like a phrasing request, which is out of scope on this SE.

Comment: Duplicate question - You will find answer here - [How to politely tell someone “No Smoking here?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/3610/how-to-politely-tell-someone-no-smoking-here)  , and [How can I ask a new date to not smoke around me, or at least gauge how such a request would go down?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/how-can-i-ask-a-new-date-to-not-smoke-around-me-or-at-least-gauge-how-such-a-re)